# Allowing only certain subclasses in Java Hibernate entity relationships

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, subclass

I'm creating a Java application with Hibernate 3.2.5. I'm developing in Netbeans 7.2, the database is MySQL 5.5. The basic idea is that of an American football game.

My current problem is in the design of the `Play` class: I want to link a `Play` with a `PlayerAction`, but on any given `Play`, only certain subclasses of `PlayerAction` can be accepted. There are several types of constraints:

- requirement constraints ("this `Play` subclass must have this `PlayerAction`")
- possibility constraints ("this `Play` subclass can have this `PlayerAction`")
- exclusion constraints ("this `Play` subclass cannot have both `PlayerAction` A and B at the same time")

Code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Play implements Countable, Serializable, Locatable {
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="play")
  private List<PlayerAction> actions;
}
```

for example, my class `PassingPlay` can only allow `PlayerActions` of types:

- `PassAction`
- `ReceptionAction`
- `SackAction`
- `InterceptionAction`
- `SackAction` excludes `ReceptionAction`

`RunningPlay` can only allow `PlayerActions` of types:

- required `RunAction`
- `TackleAction`
- `FumbleAction`

etc.

An ideal solution wouldn't have to be easy to build, as long as it's easy to maintain. My only idea currently is just giving every subclass a method returning a String[][], but that is so lame, cumbersome, and non-OO - I don't even want to begin implementing it.

Comment: Do you know about `@PrePersti`, `@PreUpdate` etc? [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html) the manual page from Hibernate 4.0 (sorry, I tried to find a link to you hibernate version, but it is quite old. Anyway, those listeners already exist in previous version). Why don't you upgrade to the latest Hibernate by the way? If you are starting a project from scratch may be useful! PS: if you need, I can provide with a "real" answer, not just with this suggestion